# What is the best way to get time backwards in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the best way to get time for recent notifications (relative to current time) in an application, which are 5 sec ago, 10 sec ago or 7 hr 32 min ago?

In other words, I have a Date Object (in format `2019-03-12T10:05:32.257`) which is for example 3 hr 6 min 9 sec ago from current time, I am wondering if there is a clean way to achieve the magic numbers 3, 6, 9 and display in html.

Comment: Are you trying to find the time difference between now, and that given date?

Comment: Yes, what is the expression for finding difference and getting it in the format of x hr y min z sec? It is guaranteed that the time difference will be less than 24 hrs.

Comment: Aside from pure javascript solutions, there are libraries that solve your problem: https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration or https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js both work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More cleaner way and generic implementation that I see to approach this problem could be.

1. Get the difference of date object in seconds converted as a first step
2. Then check for whether it could be fit into

   - years(divide by 31536000)
   - months(divide by 2592000)
   - days(divide by 86400)
   - hours(divide by 3600)
   - minutes(divide by 60)

```js
function timesAgo(date) {

  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000); // get the diffrence of date object sent with current date time of the system time

  var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000); // divide seconds by seconds in avg for a year to get years 

//conditioning based on years derived above 
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " years";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000); // months check similar to years
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " months";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400); // days check similar to above 
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " days";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600); // hours check
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " hours";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60); // minutes check 
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " minutes";
  }
  return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds"; // seconds check at the end
}


var withYears = new Date('August 19, 1999 23:15:30');
var withMonths = new Date('March 19, 2019 23:15:30');
var withDays = new Date('May 1, 2019 23:15:30');
var withPreviousDay = new Date('May 5, 2019 23:15:30');
var withHours = new Date('May 6, 2019 10:15:30');
console.log(timesAgo(withYears));
console.log(timesAgo(withMonths));
console.log(timesAgo(withDays));
console.log(timesAgo(withPreviousDay));
console.log(timesAgo(withHours));
```

Easier way If your using Angular and Moment is to use `fromNow()` function - [Link](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/02-fromnow/)

```js
console.log(moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(true)); // 12 years

console.log(moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow()); // 12 years ago
```

```html
    <script data-require="moment.js@*" data-semver="2.18.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you need an Angular Pipe check this [times-ago-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-ago-pipe)

Comment: Once again. I am looking for a one liner. A good and right Angular DatePipe.

Comment: Check my update - if your using `momentjs` this is just one liner

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to find the difference between two Date objects.

First, you can convert them to Date objects, followed by using [getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to get it in milliseconds. After which, you subtract both date objects to get the time difference, and then divide it by 1000 to get the results in seconds.

```
const targetDate = new Date('2019-03-12T10:05:32.257').getTime();
const current = new Date().getTime();
const differenceInSeconds = (current - targetDate) / 1000;
```

From there, you can convert it to your required format (hours, minutes, and seconds).

And in order to convert them into hours, minutes and seconds,

```
const hours = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds % 3600 / 60);
const seconds = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds % 3600 % 60);
```

This is how the end result will be like:

```js
const targetDate = new Date('2019-03-12T10:05:32.257').getTime();
const current = new Date().getTime();
const differenceInSeconds = (current - targetDate) / 1000;

const hours = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds / 3600);
const minutes = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds % 3600 / 60);
const seconds = Math.floor(differenceInSeconds % 3600 % 60);
const result = `${hours} hr ${minutes} min ${seconds} sec`
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is the expression for getting difference in the format of x hr y min z sec? It is guaranteed that the time difference will be less than 24 hrs.

Comment: @saint1729 done! I've updated my solution to add some context to it.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the detailed explanation. Is it possible in one line with an Angular pipe?

Comment: @saint1729 I see, you mean like writing a custom pipe, and using it within that component?

Comment: Yes. It would be even better if we use existing DatePipe and apply it to the date difference.

Comment: @saint1729 I am not sure if that can be done with the default DatePipes, because of the way JavaScript's Date object work. The `getTime()`  date method returns the value in the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch. Hence, using DatePipe on it will convert that into that format, thus the DatePipe will probably return it in year 1970 or something. Therefore, if you want to use a pipe, you have to write a custom one!

Comment: I used this logic in my custom pipe